# What is the Riva_fm_cal file?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, files

What is the `Riva_fm_cal` file?

It is located in `/data/app` on many Android devices.

It is typically a very small file (under 25 bytes), and gets recreated if deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Searching the file on Google returned a source code used by GeeksPhone: [android_hardware_fm.cpp](https://github.com/gp-b2g/frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android_hardware_fm.cpp).

From [line #199](https://github.com/gp-b2g/frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android_hardware_fm.cpp#L199), it seems the file is related to FM radio receiver calibration.

```
static jint android_hardware_fmradio_FmReceiverJNI_SetCalibrationNative
     (JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jint fd, jbyteArray buff)
{

    struct v4l2_ext_control ext_ctl;
    char tmp[CAL_DATA_SIZE] = {0x00};
    int err;
    FILE* cal_file;

    cal_file = fopen("/data/app/Riva_fm_cal", "r" );
    if(cal_file != NULL) {
        ext_ctl.id = V4L2_CID_PRIVATE_IRIS_SET_CALIBRATION;
        if (fread(&tmp[0],1,CAL_DATA_SIZE,cal_file) = 0){
            return FM_JNI_SUCCESS;
        }
    }else {
        return FM_JNI_SUCCESS;
    }
  return FM_JNI_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code is implemented inside Android framework, which means that the Android OS is the one who (re)creates this file.

Comment: **Note**: I couldn't find this file on Nexus 5 on Lollipop 5.1, so I admit I can't provide any more details beyond this.

Comment: The name certainly fits that description, "fm" for FM Radio, and "cal" for calibration.  Any idea of the "Riva" part?  I wonder if an app is creating it or if Android is creating it.  SD Maid picks it up as file to be deleted.

Comment: I honestly don't have any idea for the "Riva", searching that didn't return anything related. Also, updated the info to make it clearer.